# Problems : Read a Json and Create a List (Ionic)

Tags: angularjs, json, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to create a list but when a read the Json this error appears
How I can Fix it?

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
   import { Http } from '@angular/http';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
   import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';

   /*
    Generated class for the KpisProvider provider.

   See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
   for more info on providers and Angular DI.
   */
   @Injectable()
   export class KpisProvider {

        private url: string = 'https://private-anon-3cb8931ec8-kpisapi1.apiary-mock.com/api/Projects';

       constructor(private http: Http) {
         console.log('Hello KpisProvider Provider');
       }

       getProjects(){
         return this.http.get(this.url)
.        .do((res: Response) => console.log(res))
         .map((res: Response) => res.json());
       }

   }
```

And the error is:

Argument of type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type
            'PartialObserver'. Type '(res: Response) => void' is not assignable to type
            'CompletionObserver'. Property 'complete' is missing in type '(res: Response) => void'.

```
  L22:  return this.http.get(this.url)
  L23:  .do((res : Response) => console.log(res))
  L24:  .map((res : Response) => res.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

do you have an extra period . in the query you're running?

```
return this._http.get(this.url)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())

    .catch(this._errorHandler);
```

the method that's subscribing to the http call can log out the results

Comment: also I can't write
        return this._http.get(this.url).map(...)

Comment: `_http` is a variable reference from my example, just substitute it for your equivalent variable of `http`

Comment: I know it, but the problem es when you write (res : Respose) => res.json(). isnt assignable to parameter.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9VHfMRmKig
In this video shows how to do but I can,t and I dont know why (min 6:10)

Comment: How are you calling this method?

Comment: I'm following the same steps that the video